# CPU test pins (test as a noun)

Tags: cpu, pinout, test

Looking at the [FM2 socket](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/packages/socket_fm2#Pin_Map) for AMD processors I've noticed that there are some "test pins", i.e V22.
What are they for? Is it possible to manage them, i.e for some led signaling?

Answer (score 4):

These will be used for AMD to test their CPUs. Unless you have further information about how they work, you shouldn't use them. They probably cannot be used to control LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

Its a test port, only AMD would know what they are for. Typical CPU pins on modern cpu's are usually low voltage, under 1.4 volt and low current, so it won't drive LED's.

On a PC CPU or motherboard, a GPIO expander would be used to drive an LED.